# The difference between percentile and quantile and how to calculate each

Tags: math, statistics

I am having extreme difficulty understanding the difference between percentiles and quantile.

I have googled the two statistical measures and the statement that makes the most sense to me is:

> If you know that your score is in the 90th percentile, that means you
> scored better than 90% of people who took the test. Percentiles are
> commonly used to report scores in tests, like the SAT, GRE and LSAT.
> for example, the 70th percentile on the 2013 GRE was 156. ... The 75th
> percentile is also called the third quartile.

However, even with the above statement I'm still having trouble trying to get my head around it.

Therefore looking at the following Field Values can someone please calculate the 75th perentile/quantile of the following values in the field below called Feed_source

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this question would be better suited for statistics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In layman's terms:

Sort data array
Choose element in position `N*0.75` (index after sorting, `N` is length of array)
Value of this element is 75th procentile

Concerning your example - after sorting we have`[101, 101, 103, 104, 107]`.
Index `5*0.75=3.75 ~ 4` (round to the closest integer).
So value `104` is needed procentile.

Quantile is more general term, procentile is quantile with 0.01 resolution.